# Show Customer Orders that also had orders yesterday

Tags: qlikview, set-analysis

I am trying to create a formula that will show all orders for customers that have an order yesterday.

So if the customer has an order yesterday, show all orders for that customer but if a customer has no order yesterday then show nothing. This is the formula that I have used but it isn't customers that only had orders yesterday:

```
sum({$<[Customer Adj]=p({<[Invoice Date Num]={$(=vxToday-1)}>}), [Originating cl for order]-={'B', 'E', 'P'}, BilltoShiptoSales_Flag={0} >} 
[Cases_Aggr])
```

I will then need to limit this by only show the previous week of their orders but I can figure that out.

**Purpose of this:**
The reason for this is at my job some customers abuse Friday delivery's and as a result we have way too many Friday delivery's. We are trying to see all the customers who got Friday delivery's and then see if they get a large order earlier in the week that warrants their Friday delivery.  If not, maybe we can get them to get their order earlier in the week.

picture of result:
[image]

Comment: have you tried "sum({$<[Customer Adj]=p({<[Invoice Date Num]={$(=vxToday-1)}>} [Customer Adj]), [Originating cl for order]-={'B', 'E', 'P'}, BilltoShiptoSales_Flag={0} >} 
[Cases_Aggr])"

Comment: @EldadT same result

Comment: the maybe this part is not giving the correct result "$(=vxToday-1)"
add a new expression with that calc, don't use anything for the label. then in the table chart, you can see what expression was rendered (you will see it in the header)

Answer (score 0):

another way of doing this:

1. create a variable that stores all customers that have an order yesterday:
   `vCustomers` `=concat({<[Invoice Date Num]={$(=vxToday-1)}>} DISTINCT chr(39)&[Customer Adj] &chr(39),',')`
2. your expression now will be: `sum({$<[Customer Adj]={$(vCustomers)}, [Originating cl for order]-={'B', 'E','P'}, BilltoShiptoSales_Flag={0} >} [Cases_Aggr])`

Comment: The variable is working but the expression is not; it is giving me an error that says, "Error in set modifier ad hoc element list: ',' or ')' expected"

Comment: add a new expression with that calc, don't use anything for the label. then in the table chart, you can see what expression was rendered (you will see it in the header) . copy it here

Comment: I can't because the table is not showing up, it is just giving me the error, "Error in set modifier ad hoc element list: ',' or ')' expected"

Comment: then put a screenshot of the expression. something is wrong with the expression itself. nothing else. if you remove the variable does it work?

Comment: Eladt, I am no longer getting the error but I am receiving no results but I should be.  This I copied from my application:

sum({$<[Customer Adj]=p({<[Invoice Date Num]={$(=vxToday-1)}>}), [Originating cl for order]-={'B', 'E', 'P'}, BilltoShiptoSales_Flag={0}, [Invoice Date Num]={">=$(=vxToday6)<=$(=vMax_SO_Closed_Date-2)"}>} [Cases_Aggr])

Comment: start eliminating parameters and look where it gets no results. add one parameter at a time.
I know that the above solution works as I use it all the time, so check the other parameters. It can also be the date format...